# MagicalRecord: one to many relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, magicalrecord

I m not quite sure if it is the right approach

I want to have a one to many relationship between entity A and B, so A could refer to multiple records of B, but B only to one record of A

my question is how to do this with MagicalRecords... i m familiar with the basic fetching and creating of single entities

but have no clue how to fetch, creat, update entities with realtionships

Comment: I would just use CoreData without magical record. It's really not that difficult to use. [See here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-CJBDBHCB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to beware of the 'context' of CoreData. I usually use [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {}]; method, and create entity inside the block.

I will use my case i show above as an example,

To save a "message" to a "conversation" entity,

```
ChatConversation* chatConversation = [ChatConversation MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"conversationID" withValue:<your value> inContext:localContext];
```

^first see if there is a entity already been created using the find first by attribute method

```
ChatMessage* chatMessage = [ChatMessage MR_createInContext:localContext];
   [chatMessage set.....];
   ......

if(!chatConversation){
   //You need to create a new chatConversation entity
   chatConversation = [ChatConversation MR_createInContext:localContext];
   ......
 }
   [chatMessage setChatConversation:chatConversation];
```

2. If you want to get all message from a chat conversation, just fetchAll messages with custom predicates

   ```
   -(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if(!_fetchedResultsController)
        _fetchedResultsController = [ChatMessage MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"createdAt" ascending:TRUE withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", @"conversation.conversationID",self.conversationObject.conversationID] groupBy:nil delegate:self];

   return _fetchedResultsController;
   }
   ```

Comment: many thanks I only was missing ´[chatMessage setChatConversation:chatConversation];´ this line, and now everything works flawlessly

Comment: Hi have a question about create new relationship and create new xcdatamodel. I'm using magical record also. can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38784884/ios-how-to-make-use-of-core-data-after-adding-some-more-relationship-to-existing/38785044?noredirect=1#comment64941995_38785044

Comment: @PangHoMing what if we have two different viewControllers? I've asked the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39958526/how-to-save-objects-in-relationship-in-core-data-using-magical-records

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "how to do this with MagicalRecords"? Cause this is not handle by MagicalRecords.
They are all set in the coredata model file.
For instance, for my project, i am implementing the IM feature.
 1. One conversation -> many messages
 2. One message ->one conversation

[image]

[image]

this is the design of data model.
feel free to ask me any questions about Coredata + MR
Cheers!

Comment: the data model is clear to me... just how do I handle the relationship in code... eg how do I creat new records, how do i fatch those... `NSArray *entityA = [classA MR_findAll]; classA A = [entityA objectAtIndex:0]` how do I now get the records from B

Comment: how about create new relationship and create new xcdatamodel. I can not find something similar to [chatMessage setChatConversation:chatConversation]; after set new relationship 1 to many and inverse many to 1.

Comment: I do not have experience on this particular problem, sorry about that. I up voted your question. Wish that will help :D