# IOS How to make use of core data after adding some more relationship to existing core data?

Tags: ios, core-data, database-migration

I've decided to change my core data structure by adding few relationship (2-3) relationship. How to switch to the new core data stack but still keeping the old implementation (method, data....). Do we need to create new `xcdatamodel` and how switch to new xcdatamodel?

Any help is much appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change your data model, you need to inform CodeData of the change as well. For this  a'lightWeightMigration' is needed. 
To tell Core Data we want to perform a lightweight migration, we need to set two properties when configuring our persistent store coordinator in the startCoreData() method. 
First, NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption needs to be true, which tells Core Data to upgrade its SQLite database when the model changes. 
Second, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption also needs to be true, which tells Core Data to figure out the differences when the model changes, and apply sensible defaults if possible
create the optionsDictionary as this : 
let mOptions = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
            NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]
pass this optionsDictionary in coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: mOptions)
And you are good to go!

Comment: Hi I'm using magical record 2.3. There is this line for [MagicalRecord setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack]; does this do the same? Do I need to make additional code as per yrs suggestion?

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh sorry for the late reply, I havent worked with MagicalRecord ,iam not sure about the migration ..ill explore and get back to you

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with the existing app which is already on the Apple Store, It is very important to make a new Data Model

To Create new Data Model, Go thorough the following steps:

1. Open Xcode project/workspace
2. Select you Data Model file
3. Go to Menu and click on the Edit menu. Click on the *Add->Add Model version*.
4. Name you new model version, and select the previous active version as base model.
5. Again select the `.xcdatamodeld`, and go to file navigator. Mark the new Model as Current version.
6. Start working on the new database model.

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have done the step and create new xcdatamodel but my new relationship is not reflect. Should I recreate the 2 entity class which have new relationship?

Comment: Hi Lê Khánh Vinh

No need to recreate the entity class, you can directly create new relationships in the existing class

Comment: how to create new relationships? my old core data has type of _Article.h and Article.h but if i try to generate new NSmanageSubclass model it become ArticleCategory+CoreDataProperties.h and Article.h

Comment: No need to worries. Apple has changed the default Model class. Now Apple is providing 4 class rather then 2
You can directly create new relationships by selecting the new xcDataModel

Comment: hi I have created new relationship from the xcDataModel but can not assign value. For example I create new relationship between Article and ArticleCategory but not [article setArticleCategory] or similar method